# How to simulate roll of a dice

Tags: python

How to simulate the roll of an UNFAIR 6-sided die. Instead of each side having an even chance of coming up (1/6 = 16.7%), the middle numbers should be favored. There should be a 20% chance of rolling a 2, 3, 4, or 5, and only a 10% chance of rolling a 1 or a 6. 
Thanks

Comment: Hint: use a 10-sided die.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly was the problem? Is this a programming problem or a math problem?

Comment: programming problem, I m stuck in the logic! what should i do, so that the probablity of middle numbers become 20%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got numpy installed, you could use `numpy.random.choice` to sample with a given probability distribution.

```
import numpy as np
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
probs = [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]
sample = np.random.choice(values, p=probs)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility:

```
import random
result = random.choices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], weights=[10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10])[0]
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it lots of ways. This is one of the easier ones :

```
from random import choice
options = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
result = choice(options)
print(result)
```

There are 10 values. The percentage of probability of getting 1 is (1/10)*100 = 10%, the percentage of the probability of getting 2 is (2/10)*100=20%......

Comment: How this will make the probablity of numbers 2,3,4,5  as 20%. Please explain

Comment: This answer takes advantage of the fact that your intended probabilities are multiples of 10%

Comment: @M.Usaid Please have a look to my updated explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

die_roll = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 7, 1), p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1])
```